# Windows API CRect Inverting so works like graph paper

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc

I guess i am old school when it comes to doing graphics (graphs) etc.
My Brain = Bottom/Left is 0,0, Top is Size y, Right is Size x
DC Rect = Top/Left is 0,0, Bottom is Size y, Right is Size x

Hence I find drawing in Windows DC Rect a pain as Y is inverted and I have to flip my brain for each drawing function.

Is there a way to draw in Rect or DC in graph mode and/or flip/mirror it into the Windows dc rect?

Comment: Normally off-screen drawing is done in a bitmap built with CreateCompatibleBitmap.  Windows bitmaps by default are indexed bottom-up which is what I consider to be inverted-Y (because that's not how images or screen space are normally represented) and then you can BitBlt it.  If you're not performing graph-related drawing or it's not for a game with Y-up coordinates I'd urge you to just get used to screen coordinates.  If you do all your WinAPI drawing calls using reversed Y coordinates you'll confuse the heck out of anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the viewport origin anywhere you like. This is done using either [`SetViewportOrgEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setviewportorgex) (GDI) or [`CDC::SetViewportOrg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#setviewportorg) in MFC.

The fundamentals are explained in Microsoft's documentation under [Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/coordinate-spaces-and-transformations).

While this moves the viewport origin to an arbitrary position, it doesn't flip the orientation along the y-axis. There are several ways to accomplish that, though the easiest is probably to take advantage of adjustable viewport scaling ([`ScaleViewportExtEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-scaleviewportextex), or [`CDC::ScaleViewportExt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#scaleviewportext)). The following `OnPaint` implementation draws a line from (0, 0) to (height, width). With the viewport adjustments in place, this line goes from the bottom left to the top right.

```cpp
void CSampleDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc{ this };

    CRect rc{};
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    auto const width{ rc.right - rc.left };
    auto const height{ rc.bottom - rc.top };

    dc.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetViewportOrg(0, height);
    dc.ScaleViewportExt(1, 1, -1, 1);

    dc.MoveTo(0, 0);
    dc.LineTo(width, height);
}
```

Comment: IInspectable
Thanks for that info, i'll have a look at SetViewPortOrg.
Think where i am getting most bothered is last win app i wrote used win32 api and got used to x,cx,y,cy  hence MFC left/right top/bottom is double brian effort :-)

Comment: IInspectable 
Tried your solution, works a treat many many thanks.
imk